# Cocos2D blocked buttons after replceScene and removeAllDelegates

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, blocked

I have a serious problem with Cocos2d.

1) I have one scene with few buttons in it
2) I have another scene in which i use

```
    -(void) onEnter {
      [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowTouches:YES];
      [super onEnter];
    }
```

and also

```
-(void) onExit {
   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
   [super onExit];
}
```

3) After replacing 1st scene to the 2nd everything is ok
4) But after returing to 1st scene (by replaceScene) all buttons on 1st scene are blocked. Nothing works
5) If i'm not using "removeDelegate" in "onExit()" buttons on 1st scene work, but touches from the 2nd scene are still active.

Comment: I do the same things and it works very well about the touch dispatcher. How do you replace your scene and what are your buttons?

Comment: The answer is: remove touches in onExitTransitionDidStart